# How to prove or disprove statements about sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Prove or disprove:
>
> 1. The set: $\{ \emptyset\}^{\Bbb N}$ has only one element.
> 2. The set $\emptyset^{\Bbb N}$ is empty.

I'm pretty sure both are true, for 1. all the natural numbers go to the empty set and that is the only element. Where as 2. all the natural numbers go to nothing so that's why it's empty. (Same as $ {\Bbb N}^{\emptyset} $ nothing goes to something is nothing (I think)).

The problem is I have no idea how to show this so advice would be appreciated.

---

Edit:
My defintion of a function is:

$f:B\to A$ if  $(a_1,b),(a_2,b)\in f \ \Rightarrow \ a_1=a_2$

So for 2. I can simply say that: $(1,\emptyset),(2,\emptyset)\in f \Rightarrow a_1\neq a_2$  ?

Comment: Your ideas are correct (well, except that $\mathbb{N}^\emptyset$ has one element).  If you want a rigorous proof, try beginning with the formal definition of a function (as a set of ordered pairs satisfying certain properties).

Comment: @universalset Please see my edit.

Comment: In the definition of $f\colon B\to A$ we also require that the domain of $f$ is $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first one, take two functions and show they are equal. Remember that two functions with the same domain are equal if and only if they give the same result for every point in that domain.

For the second you should recall the definition of a function, and conclude that there are not functions from a nonempty set into the empty set.

Comment: You mean actual functions ? Like $f(x)=\frac{x}0$ and $f(y)=\frac{y}0$ ?

Comment: Functions are not formulas of arithmetic. Functions are sets of ordered pairs with certain properties.

Comment: I see. so $(1,\{\emptyset\})=(2,\{\emptyset\})$.

Comment: What? That makes no sense.

Comment: Aren't these ordered pairs of functions that goes from 1 or 2 to $\{\emptyset\}$ ? (both equal $\{\emptyset\}$)

Comment: Ordered pairs are only equal if both coordinates are equal. Your claim implies $1=1$. But if $f\colon\Bbb N\to\{\varnothing\}$, then all the ordered pairs must have the form $(n,\varnothing)$. This doesn't leave much choice to have more than one function like that.

Answer (score 1):

In 1. you rightly consider the constant map which assignes the empty set (viewed as the sole member of your codomain $\{\emptyset\}$) to each natural number. In 2. the codomain is the empty set, not the set whose sole member is the empty set, so you can assign no value to any point in the domain, hence no function. Beware that $\mathbb{N}^\emptyset$ is actually the singleton, since it contains the so-called "empty function".

Comment: oops universalset beat me

Comment: For 1. by constant map you mean like $\phi: \{ \emptyset , \forall  x \in \Bbb N$ ? For 2. please check my edit, is this what you meant ?

Comment: Yes for 1. I mean the constant map as you describe. The definition of function in your edit seems wrong: I would have written $(a,b_1), (a,b_2)\in f\implies b_1=b_2$, meaning that you must assign one single value to each element of the domain.